# Append to Zend\Navigation

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-navigation

- In my application I have a global navigation.
- In each module, depending on module state etc I attach elements to navigation.

The simplified code in `Module.php`:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
  $navigation = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Navigation');
  $navigation->addPages($pages);
```

It works when I attach top-level elements.

But I have no idea how to add a sub-item. For example, I have top level menu position "Settings" and each module add a sub-level link to its own settings and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution to the problem - which I'm still waiting. I will describe a workaround that solved my problem.

- I created a static navigation in the configuration file. (module.config.php)
- I used \Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl

based on this tutorials:

http://ivangospodinow.com/zend-framework-2-acl-setup-in-5-minutes-tutorial/
http://www.ivangospodinow.com/zend-framework-2-navigation-with-acl/

works very well - but I still would like to be able to operate more flexibly on navigation - as described in my question...